How to refresh form data in Filament?
I have a Game object which can be controlled via the GamesResource. Here I have following section with actions and status messages inside my form:
Section::make('Game control')
  ->schema([
    Forms\Components\Placeholder::make('status')
        ->label('Current status')
        ->content(function ($record) {
            if (!$record->is_running && !$record->current_round && !$record->is_finished) {
                return 'The game has not started yet.';
            } elseif ($record->is_finished && !$record->is_running) {
                return 'Game finished.';
            } else {
                return 'Current round: ' . $record->currentRound->sort;
            }
        }),
    Forms\Components\Actions::make([
        Forms\Components\Actions\Action::make('startGame')
            ->label('Start game')
            ->button()
            ->visible(fn($record) => !$record->is_running && !$record->is_finished)
            ->action(function (Game $record, EditRecord $livewire) {
                $record->startGame();
                $livewire->refreshFormData(['is_running', 'is_finished', 'current_round']);
            }),
        Forms\Components\Actions\Action::make('startNextRound')
            ->label('Next Round')
            ->button()
            ->visible(fn($record) => $record->is_running && !$record->isLastRound())
            ->action(function (Game $record, EditRecord $livewire) {
                $record->startNextRound();
                $livewire->refreshFormData(['is_running', 'is_finished', 'current_round']);
            }),
        Forms\Components\Actions\Action::make('finishGame')
            ->label('Show results')
            ->button()
            ->visible(fn($record) => $record->is_running && $record->isLastRound())
            ->action(function (Game $record, EditRecord $livewire) {
                $record->finishGame();
                $livewire->refreshFormData(['is_running', 'is_finished', 'current_round']);
            })
    ]),
  ])
  ->visibleOn('edit')

This is part of my Game model:
class Game extends Model {
    public function isLastRound() {
        return $this->current_round // check if current round is set
            && $this->rounds()->count() === $this->currentRound->sort; // check if current round is the last round
    }

    public function startGame() {
        $this->is_running = true;
        $this->current_round = $this->rounds()->orderBy('sort')->first()->id;
        $this->save();
    }

    public function startNextRound() {
        $currentRoundSort = $this->rounds()->where('id', $this->current_round)->first()->sort;
        $nextRound = $this->rounds()->where('sort', $currentRoundSort + 1)->first();
        $this->current_round = $nextRound->id;
        $this->save();
    }

    public function finishGame() {
        $this->is_running = false;
        $this->is_finished = true;
        $this->save();
    }
}

Currently everything works (nearly) as desired: The status messages show the correct status, the buttons apply the correct changes to the Game object. But clicking a button, for example "Next round", needs me to refresh the page manually in order to see the change of status from "Current round: 1" to "Current round: 2".
How do I achieve an automatic refresh, either of the page, or the section or the whole form?
I stumbled upon EditRecord::refreshFormData(), but couldn't really make it work properly: Funnily enough, the current solution works for Starting and Finishing the game, but not for Next Round.
